# Best way to implement Web GUI for administration of a database?

Tags: database, user-interface, web

If I ever wanted to implement a Web GUI for a database which interacts with websphere application server / JBOSS , how would I do that?
Sorry if this is a very basic question but I'm a newbie to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry your question seems a little vague. Do you want to have a Database with GUI? If so look into phpmyadmin is a great free database using mySQL. It should work with anything that can work with an sql database. The commands might be very slightly different, but almost all SQL databases are the same i believe.